# Installing Virtualbox Extension pack with Puppet

Tags: virtualbox, puppet

I tried googling this but got 5000 hits on people using vagrant with virtualbox..

Since my virtualbox has machines requiring USB support I need the extension pack installed.

I need to have puppet install my extension pack file.

I currently have this for VirtualBox:

```
class virtualbox(
  $ubuntu_release
) {
  apt::source { virtualbox:
    location    => 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian',
    release     => $ubuntu_release,
    repos       => 'contrib',
    key         => '98AB5139',
    key_source  => "http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc",
    include_src => false,
  }
  package { virtualbox:
    name => 'virtualbox-4.2',
    ensure => present,
    require => Apt::Source['virtualbox']
  }
}
```

Do anyone have a way to install the extension pack ?
Im afraid if I do an exec I have no way of checking if I actually installed the pack or what version it is on so it will just keep reinstalling.
And since the extension pack updates everytime there is a new VirtualBox version I need to be able to update it as well ..

Here's the current command(s) to install the pack.

```
wget -nv http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.10-84104.vbox-extpack -P /tmp && VBoxManage extpack install /tmp/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.10-84104.vbox-extpack --replace
```

I tried doing something like having a version of the extension pack in a file:

```
class vbox_extension {
    $packagever = "4210"
    $packagefile = "/var/log/puppet/vbox_extension.ver"
    exec { "vboxinst":
    command => "wget -nv http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.10-84104.vbox-extpack -P /tmp \
                && VBoxManage extpack install /tmp/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.10-84104.vbox-extpack --replace \
                && echo \"$packagever\" > \"$packagefile\"",",
    unless  => "test \"`cat $packagefile 2>/dev/null`\" = \"$packagever\"",
    require => virtualbox
    }
}
```

But is this really the cleanest way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to create a debian package of this instead as we are running our own repo anyway.

Running this on Ubuntu 12.10 for a 12.04 system.

Here's the steps:

Be root..

```
sudo su
```

You need FPM, FPM needs rubygems to install.

```
apt-get install rubygems
gem install fpm
```

And run this:

```
mkdir -p /opt/vbext
cd /opt/vbext
wget -nv http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.10-84104.vbox-extpack
cat <<EOF> /opt/vbext/installpack
#/bin/bash
VBoxManage extpack install /opt/vbext/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.10-84104.vbox-extpack --replace
EOF
cat <<EOF> /opt/vbext/removepack
#/bin/bash
vboxmanage extpack uninstall "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack"
EOF
chmod +x installpack removepack
fpm -t deb -n extpack -v 4.2.10-84104 -d virtualbox-4.2 --after-install installpack --after-remove removepack -s dir /opt/vbext/
```

You will now have a neatly packaged debian package.

```
ls /opt/vbext/*.deb
extpack_4.2.10-84104_amd64.deb
```

FPM supports templating the scripts but I'm to lazy to put that in right now..